# Распознание формата изображения до скачивания

Tags: c#, html

Программа получает все ссылки на изображения на странице и скачивает их.
Проблема в точном распознавании формата до скачивания. Допустим после скачивания я могу получить MIME-тип с помощью

```
ContentType contentType = new ContentType(_webClient.ResponseHeaders.GetValues("Content-Type")[0]);
```

Но можно ли получить эту инфу до скачивания файла?

Comment: Выполнить HEAD запрос

Comment: Кроме выполнения отдельного HEAD запроса, можно начинать скачивание в потоковом режиме, т.е. без предварительной буферизации. Данные заголовка будут реально доступны до того, как закончится скачивание, но скачивание начнется.